# Connecting Android, Webservices and database

Tags: android, database, webserver

What I'm trying to do is connect a Java Android app with a FireBird database that is stored in an enterprise server.
I realised i need to use some kind of webserver to avoid connecting to the database directly.
In other words, something like this:

Android app -> WebServer -> Database

My problem is that although there are plenty of examples none of them let me do it.
Where can I find a full example of making the webserver, retrieve data (images, datasets, etc.) and how to connect my clients to it.

And obviously if there is a better way to do what I need that I'm not aware of.

Thanks in advance.